# Mock itself throwing exception

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock a function to throw an exception like this

```
BigQueryIO mockb = mock(BigQueryIO.class);

when(mockb.getClass().getDeclaredField("SOME_FIELD"))
        .thenThrow(new NoSuchFieldException());
```

it's throwing NoSuchFieldException in the test mock itself.

I have also tried this way

```
when(BigQueryIO.class.getDeclaredField("SOME_FIELD"))
        .thenThrow(new NoSuchFieldException());
```

but this is also not working,

Am I missing some basic thing?
Does mock work differently with .class?

Comment: for .class mock is not needed

Comment: have you tried `doThrow(...).when(..)`

Comment: Yes I have tried doThrow() but since getClass() is final method so I am having issues there also